# Adding _cls to existing mongodb collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine, morphia

I have an existing MongoDB without the _cls field in the documents.

Data will continue to enter the DB during the lifetime of the DB, data is added through Morphia which doesn't add the _cls field automatically.

It seems not the best idea to add a _cls field to Morphia Entities.

Do you have a better idea how to make the data coming from morphia better fit (have the _cls field) in mongo documents?

Edit:
*I am using flask server in python with mongoengine which require the field
I saw the solution for using @PreSave in Morphia, it is a good Idea and I will use it if another solution is not found. ** I am looking for a solution in the Python side**. you aren't always able to change the data insertion

Answer (score 0):

You could use Morphia’s @PreSave annotation to ‘tweak’ the JSON document prior to it being saved to the database. You could then just inject the _cls field and value without having to declare a field in your Java class